# Adjust time scale in d3js

Tags: d3.js

```
  var data;
      data = [
                {"date":"1-May-12 11:00 AM","TPH":2},
                {"date":"1-May-12 12:00 PM","TPH":3},
                {"date":"1-May-12 1:00 PM","TPH":2},
                {"date":"1-May-12 2:00 PM","TPH":4},
                {"date":"1-May-12 3:00 PM","TPH":2},
                {"date":"1-May-12 4:00 PM","TPH":3}
             ];
        //  var passedheight = this.getHeight();
        //var containerWidth = jQuery.sap.byId(this.oParent.sId).width() || 800; // gets super parent width
        var containerWidth = $("#"+this.getId()).parent().width(); // gets immediate parent width
        var containerheight = $("#"+this.getId()).parent().height();
        var margin = {top: 15, right: 30, bottom: 20, left: 30},
        width = containerWidth- margin.left - margin.right,
         height = containerheight - margin.top - margin.bottom;
        var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y %H:%M %p").parse;
        var maxDate = parseDate(d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
        var minDate = d3.time.hour.offset(parseDate(d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.date; })),-2);

        var x = d3.time.scale()
        .domain([minDate, maxDate])
        .range([0, width]);

        var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([height, 0]);

        var color = d3.scale.category10();

        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("bottom").ticks(4);

        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y)
            .orient("left").ticks(4).tickSize(-width, 0, 0);

        var line = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
            .y(function(d) { return y(d.tonneValue); });

        var svg = d3.select("#"+this.getId()).append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
          .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

          color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "date"; }));

          data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.date = parseDate(d.date);
          });

          var wsfs = color.domain().map(function(name) {
            return {
              name: name,
              values: data.map(function(d) {
                return {date: d.date, tonneValue: +d[name]};
              })
            };
          });

          x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));

          y.domain([
            //d3.min(wsfs, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(v) { return v.tonneValue; }); }),
            0,
            d3.max(wsfs, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.tonneValue; }); })
          ]);

          svg.append("g")
              .attr("class", "x axis")
              .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
              .call(xAxis);

          svg.append("g")
              .attr("class", "y axis")
              .call(yAxis);

          var wsf = svg.selectAll(".wsf")
              .data(wsfs)
              .enter().append("g")
              .attr("class", "wsf");

          wsf.append("path")
              .attr("class", "line")
              .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
              .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

          var legendNames = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "date" });

          data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.ages = legendNames.map(function(name) { return {name: name, value: +d[name]}; });
          });
         var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
              .data(legendNames.slice())
            .enter().append("g")
              .attr("class", "legend")
              .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

          legend.append("rect")
              .attr("x", width - 18)
              .attr("width", 18)
              .attr("height", 4)
              .style("fill", function(d) {return color(d); });

          legend.append("text")
              .attr("x", width - 24)
              .attr("y", 6)
              .attr("dy", ".35em")
              .style("text-anchor", "end")
              .text(function(d) {  return d; });
```

As per above code I get the data similar to the below image (data is not exact): 
[image]

But in my code I have tried to achieve extra range where the range should start at 10 AM and end at 4 PM i.e. the line should start at x: 11 AM and y: 2 and there should be some space before from 10 AM to 11 AM but in my case the line is starting from 2 straight away. And the ticks are also random.

Added:  [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/y2n5uqe0/1/)

Comment: can you create a fiddle with your code?

Comment: @iulian Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y2n5uqe0/1/) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'll comment this line (nr 63 in your fiddle):

`x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));`

Your code will work as expected.

You did correctly when you took an offset of the `minDate` from your data, but later on you have overwritten your `x.domain` with exact min and max from your data.

Comment: Thanks got it but that take away my scale values as my data varies from `11:44 AM to 4:44 PM` so I was expecting the scale values such as `(11 am , 12 pm ... 5pm)` but instead now it is just `12 pm and 3 pm`. Am I missing something [here](https://jsfiddle.net/y2n5uqe0/24/)

Comment: Got I just need to subtract -1 to divide the ticks equally

Comment: @SiddharthPolisiti check out the `d3.time.scale` documentations for [ticks](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales#ticks). You can specify the rule by which to generate your ticks, or you can even define exactly what ticks to display.